# A generalization of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

If $A$ is an operator and $A \in \mathcal{B_{+}(X)}$ (the set of the positive operators) then the generalization of the Cauchy-Buniakowsky-Schwarz inequality holds:

$$|\langle Ax,y\rangle| \leq \langle Ax,x\rangle^{1/2}\langle Ay,y\rangle^{1/2}.$$

I don't understand a step of the proof, so I write a part of it:

First case, if $|\langle Ax,x\rangle|=|\langle Ay,y\rangle|=0$

$$0 \leq \langle A(x+\lambda y), x+\lambda y\rangle=\langle Ax,x\rangle+\lambda \langle Ay,x\rangle+\overline{\lambda}\langle Ax,y\rangle+|\lambda|^{2}\langle Ay,y\rangle$$

Now my question:

> Why is $$\mathcal{Re}\left(\overline{\lambda} \langle Ax,y\rangle \right) \geq 0 ? \tag{1}$$
>
> and why does $(1)$ imply $\langle Ax,y\rangle=0$ ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $0 \leq \langle A(x+\lambda y), x+\lambda y\rangle=\langle Ax,x\rangle+\lambda \langle Ay,x\rangle+\overline{\lambda}\langle Ax,y\rangle+|\lambda|^{2}\langle Ay,y\rangle$ and the first and last terms are zero. So $0 \leq\lambda \langle Ay,x\rangle+\overline{\lambda}\langle Ax,y\rangle$.

Using properties of the inner product and the self-adjointness of $A$ gives $0\le \overline{\langle\overline{\lambda} Ax,y\rangle}+\langle\overline{\lambda} Ax,y\rangle = 2Re \langle\overline{\lambda} Ax,y\rangle$, hence (1). Note that (1) holds for every $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$.

The only complex number $z$ with $Re (w z)\ge 0$ for every $w\in \mathbb{C}$ is $z=0$. [Exercise: prove this by considering $w=\pm1,\pm i$.] Apply this to (1) with $w=\overline{\lambda}$ and $z=\langle Ax,y\rangle$ to get $\langle Ax,y\rangle=0$.

Comment: can you explain me please from where : $\displaystyle \overline{\langle\overline{\lambda} Ax,y\rangle}$

Comment: $\lambda\langle Ay,x\rangle = \lambda\langle y,A^*x\rangle = \lambda\langle y,Ax\rangle = \lambda\overline{\langle Ax,y\rangle} = \overline{\overline{\lambda}\langle Ax,y\rangle}=\overline{\langle{\overline{\lambda}Ax,y\rangle}}$

Comment: Where is the condition that $A$ is selfadjoint?
Also, how to prove the inequality when $|<Ax,x>|=|<Ay,y>|\neq 0$

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic positive implies self-adjoint. For the other case I guess you should post a new question.